Parsing String to i:32 compiles in Rust but program don't start at first and shows unexpected behaviour
I am learning rust and I had to take input from user and that had to be i:32 so I just did.
let mut input: String = String::new();
io::stdin()
    .read_line(&mut input)
    .expect("Failed to read line");
let num: i32 = input.trim().parse().expect("failed to parse);

When I did this it compiled but program did not start. No output even print!() before any io operation did not print. So I checked weather io operation is going fine or not so i just checked the input by reading it and printing it as it is. It worked fine. So I wanted to investigate this line.
let num: i32 = input.trim().parse().expect("failed to parse); I tried it with out .trim(). Still it did not work.
So, in separate project. I ran this.
use std::io;
fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();
    print!("enter some number");
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Failed to read line");
    let num: i32 = input.trim().parse().expect("Cant convert to i32");
    println!("you entered: {num}");
}

I didn't get any output as expected but I entered a number anyways then, I got this.
nimes@nimes:~/Desktop/Rust/learning$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running `target/debug/learning`
4654541
enter some numberyou entered: 4654541

